# I want to replace fetch with axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to replace fetch with `axios`, but can not get it working. Can Anyone help?

I have following code:

```js
fetch(API_ENDPOINT + 'signup', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: data,
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS });
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response });
    navigator.resetTo({
      screen: 'carapp.Phone',
      animated: true,
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check axios documentation here: https://github.com/axios/axios
And refer to the "Performing POST requests", there you can see this sample:

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**/user** is your **API_ENDPOINT + "signup"**, and **{
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
      }** is your body. So what you need to do to make it work is the following:

```
axios.post(API_ENDPOINT + "signup", body)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS });
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response });
    navigator.resetTo({
        screen: 'carapp.Phone',
        animated: true
    });
  })
```

And of course, make sure you import and install axios.